# SQL EXCEPT ignore some columns during compare

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Assume I have the following tables:

`##TABLE1`

```
FirstName, LastName,     AsOfDate, NoOfEpisodes
     Bart,  Simpson,   07/01/2018,          123
     Lisa,  Simpson,   03/01/2018,          110
```

`##TABLE2`

```
FirstName, LastName,     AsOfDate, NoOfEpisodes
     Bart,  Simpson,   08/01/2018,          123
     Lisa,  Simpson,   08/01/2018,          130
```

If I run the following SQL command to find the differences between the two tables:

```
select * from ##TABLE2 
except (select * from ##TABLE1)
```

The result would be

```
  FirstName, LastName,     AsOfDate, NoOfEpisodes
       Bart,  Simpson,   08/01/2018,          123
       Lisa,  Simpson,   08/01/2018,          130
```

I would like to run this comparison but ignore the `AsOfDate` field yet keep it in the final results.  If I do this SQL:

```
select FirstName, LastName, NoOfEpisodes
from ##TABLE2 
except (select FirstName, LastName, NoOfEpisodes from ##TABLE1)
```

the results would look like this

```
  FirstName, LastName,  NoOfEpisodes
       Lisa,  Simpson,           130
```

but I need it to look like this

```
FirstName, LastName,     AsOfDate, NoOfEpisodes
     Lisa,  Simpson,   08/01/2018,          130
```

Obviously this is a sample set of data.  The data in production may contain 20-30 columns and I would only want to exclude a few at most.  I was hoping there might be something like an 'IGNORE' or 'NOT IN' function that I could apply to the SQL script to exclude just a couple of columns.

Comment: There are a number of ways to get the results you want, but they all involve specifying column names. Right click <table_name> -> `Select top N rows` is your friend, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about?

```
SELECT T1.FirstName, T1.LastName, T2.AsOfDate, T2.NoOfEpisodes
FROM ##TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN ##TABLE2 T2 
     ON T1.FirstName = T2.FirstName AND T1.LastName = T2.LastName
WHERE T1.NoOfEpisodes != T2.NoOfEpisodes
```

Ok, per your comment. What if we go with a CTE?

```
;WITH ex as (
   select FirstName, LastName, NoOfEpisodes
   from ##TABLE2 
   except (select FirstName, LastName, NoOfEpisodes from ##TABLE1)
)
SELECT ex.FistName, ex.LastName, ex.NoOfEpisodes, T2.AsOfDate
FROM ex
INNER JOIN ##TABLE2 T2
   ON ex.FirstName = T2.FirstName AND ex.LastName = T2.LastName
```

If the columns are getting too many to deal with, you can use excel to write the SQL where clause for you. Open SSMS and "Select top 1000 Rows" which will give you a list of the columns for the table. Copy that list and paste it into excel's A column. Then in the B column, add this function:

```
="OR T1." & A1 & " != T2." & A1
```

Copy that function to all rows in B and then you can copy the values which will be a long list of conditions to put in the where clause. You can to the same this with the SELECT list:

```
="T2." & A144 & ", "
```

Comment: The EXCEPT clause looks at all the columns, not just 'NoOfEpisodes' so if a name changed that would also show up in the result set.  And as the list of columns grows it becomes painful to try and manage all of the "or T1.x != T2.x" clauses.

Comment: Well you still are going to have to manage those columns by adding them to the two select lists in the second query you provided. I will add another query to my answer that may be helpful.